# Push message to websocket client without a request

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

I am making a Play web-socket app. When a client connects, I want to send a welcome message.
The code I use is below:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Concurrent
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

object Test extends Controller {
  def index = WebSocket.using[String] { _ => 
    val (out,channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]          
    channel.push("Welcome to MyWebSocket")
    val in = Iteratee.foreach[String] {
      _ match {
        case any => channel.push(any)
      }
    }
    (in, out)
  }
}
```

The code works fine when a client sends a message and the server has to respond to it. However, the initial welcome message `Welcome to MyWebSocket` is not sent. How can I fix this code?

**[EDIT]**

I kind of figured out the problem, but not a solution yet. The problem probably occurs because the websocket is not yet initialized when the welcome message is being pushed. I modified the code and replaced:

```
channel.push("Welcome to MyWebSocket")
```

with

```
val a = scala.concurrent.Future {
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  channel.push("Welcome to MyWebSocket")
}
```

After this I get the expected results (welcome message received by client). I think using the above approach (`Thread.sleep` and `Future`) is not the right way to solve this problem, so other solutions are welcome. It could also be a problem with the client side code which takes a while to initialize the socket. I used Firefox and [echo web-socket test](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) for the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebSocket.acceptWithActor helper method ([have a look at this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.1/ScalaWebSockets)) and in actor body make something like

```
out ! "Welcome to MyWebSocket"
```

It works nicely.